# Will it be right to use this sentence "I'm kind of a writer these days." Normally?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm kind of a writer these days.

Comment: What do you consider 'normal'? If you want to sell books, you have to decide on how your potential audience will view your use of this register. It might actually increase sales. I'd love it to have been first used by Shakespeare or Mark Twain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, depending on the context. If you're being asked about your hobbies in a professional interview I might err on the side of safety and use more formal language. However, in everyday speech, it is appropriate.